# why is it giving incorrect syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have made 3 tables in SQL server named t_user_master,t_product_master and t_transaction.The t_user_master is linked with t_transaction through the columns Users_id and t _product_master is linked with t_transaction though the columns Products_id.Now I have to generate and output which consists of users_name(from t_user_master),Product_name(from t_product_master) linked with it so as to see which used ordered which product as so on.
Here is a snippet of my code-

```
 SELECT um.Users_Name,
       pm.Product_Name,
       (SELECT SUM(Transaction_Amount)
        FROM   t_transaction
        WHERE  Transaction_Type = 'Order'
        GROUP  BY Users_Id,
                  Product_Id) AS Ordered_quantity,
       (SELECT SUM(Transaction_Amount)
        FROM   t_transaction
        WHERE  Transaction_Type = 'Payment'
        GROUP  BY Users_ID,
                  Product_Id) AS Amount_Paid,
       (SELECT MAX(Transaction_Date)
        FROM   t_transaction
        GROUP  BY Users_Id,
                  Product_Id) AS Last_Transaction_Date,
       (SELECT ( ( SUM(Transaction_Amount) * pm.Cost_per_Item ) - SUM(Transaction_Amount) ) )AS Balance
        FROM   t_user_master um
               JOIN t_transaction tr
                 ON um.Users_ID = tr.Users_ID
               JOIN t_product_master pm
                 ON tr.Product_ID = pm.Product_ID
    GROUP BY um.Users_Name,pm.Product_Name
```

I have recitified all the errors related to syntax but now I am facing another problem.After executing it I am getting this message -Column 't_product_master.Cost_Per_Item' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Can you give the exact error? it should give you the exact point it has found the problem such as : `Incorrect syntax near 'xxx`

Comment: @ChrisL L This is the exact error-Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 80
Incorrect syntax near 'Product_Name'..Here the line 80 points to last line

Answer (score 1):

You missed a ")" at the end of the 10th line and a "," after `Last_Transaction_Date`. Try this:

```
SELECT    um.Users_Name,pm.Product_Name,
(SELECT   SUM(Transaction_Amount)
 FROM     t_transaction 
 WHERE    Transaction_Type='Order' 
 GROUP BY Users_Id,Product_Id
) AS Ordered_quantity,
(SELECT   SUM(Transaction_Amount)
 FROM     t_transaction 
 WHERE    Transaction_Type='Payment'
 GROUP BY Users_ID,Product_Id
) AS Amount_Paid,
(SELECT   MAX(Transaction_Date)
 FROM     t_transaction 
 GROUP BY Users_Id,Product_Id
) AS Last_Transaction_Date,
(SELECT   ( ( SUM(Transaction_Amount)*pm.Cost_per_Item ) - SUM(Transaction_Amount) )
) AS Balance
FROM      t_user_master um 
JOIN      t_transaction tr ON um.Users_ID=tr.Users_ID
JOIN      t_product_master pm ON tr.Product_ID = pm.Product_ID

GROUP BY um.Users_Name,pm.Product_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least you're missing a "," at the end of this line:

```
GROUP BY Users_Id,Product_Id) AS Last_Transaction_Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after LastTransactionDate and the last column of your SELECT looks to be malformed, i.e.

```
(SELECT ((SUM(Transaction_Amount)*pm.Cost_per_Item)-SUM(Transaction_Amount)) AS Balance
```

Comment: even after rectifying that error,its still giving the same error.

Comment: Your subqueries have issues as well `(SELECT SUM(Transaction_Amount)
        FROM   t_transaction
        WHERE  Transaction_Type = 'Order'
        GROUP  BY Users_Id,
                  Product_Id) AS Ordered_quantity` will return multiple rows.  Its not allowed in subqueries.  You really need to look at rewriting the query.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually three issues in your query:

1. A missing comma after Last_Transaction_Date.
2. Ending bracket while selecting Balance.
3. When calculating balance you have used pm.Cost_per_Item. Once you do GROUP BY all the select statement columns are calculated on resulting grouped rows. I have used sum but you can use any other aggregate function as required.

Correct query is:

```
SELECT um.Users_Name,
    pm.Product_Name,
    (SELECT SUM(Transaction_Amount) FROM t_transaction 
    WHERE Transaction_Type='Order' 
    GROUP BY Users_Id,Product_Id) AS Ordered_quantity,
    (SELECT SUM(Transaction_Amount) FROM t_transaction 
    WHERE Transaction_Type='Payment'
    GROUP BY Users_ID,Product_Id )AS Amount_Paid,
    (SELECT MAX(Transaction_Date) FROM t_transaction 
      GROUP BY Users_Id,Product_Id) AS Last_Transaction_Date, -- error 1
     (SELECT ((SUM(Transaction_Amount)* sum(pm.Cost_per_Item))-SUM(Transaction_Amount))) AS 
      Balance -- error 2 and error 3
FROM t_user_master um 
JOIN t_transaction tr ON um.Users_ID=tr.Users_ID
JOIN t_product_master pm ON tr.Product_ID = pm.Product_ID
GROUP BY um.Users_Name,pm.Product_Name ;
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: @deepshika I cant get what changes you made with respect to the third error

Comment: To get Balance amount you have used t_product_master.Cost_per_Item value. This should also be aggregated to a scalar value (i.e. using Max, Sum, Min any function based on your requirement) to get the correct result.